# Missing tabu.sty in Travis CI build

Tags: latex, travis-ci, pdftex

I am trying to use Travis CI to ensure LaTeX documents compile. I am having an issue where, despite installing what I think are the proper LaTeX packages, the build still fails with:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
! LaTeX Error: File `tabu.sty' not found.
```

I did a quick search to find that `tabu.sty` was in the package `texlive-latex-extra`, which I am installing.

```
apt-cache search tabu | grep tex
```

Here are the relevant sections of the Travis CI config:

```
language: generic
cache:
    - apt
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get -qq update
  - sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install -y texlive-full texlive-latex-extra python-pygments latex-xcolor texlive-pictures
```

I have even tried to install all LaTeX dependencies, using the following (and also using `texlive-full`):

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get -qq update
  - sudo apt-get install texlive-{base,bibtex-extra,extra-utils,generic-recommended,fonts-recommended,font-utils,latex-base,latex-recommended,latex-extra,math-extra,pictures,pstricks,science} perl-tk purifyeps chktex latexmk dvipng xindy dvidvi fragmaster lacheck latexdiff libfile-which-perl dot2tex tipa latex-xcolor latex-beamer prosper pgf python-pygments texlive-latex-extra
```

When I try to mock out what Travis is doing, (spinning up a VM, checking out the repository, running the scripts), everything works.

- Why would Travis CI have a discrepancy from my VM?
- How do I install `tabu.sty`?

I'm really at a loss at what to do and any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Update: I ended up [installing LaTeX from source](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/raw/master/install-tl-ubuntu). Travis CI seems to not like LaTeX packages installed via `apt-get`.